# Umbraco 7 upgrade blank screen: unexpected token >

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We are attempting to upgrade an umbraco 7.2.8 site to umbraco 7.5.8. When I load the backoffice to get a hold of the upgrade wizard, I am presented with a blank screen. When I inspect element, I see this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. The reference to the error is: `/umbraco/Application?umb__rnd=ffffffffb6d9a809`.

Has anyone seen this error during an upgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I navigated to the Sources tab of the chrome dev tools and found the `Application?umb__rnd`. I attached a screenshot of what I saw. It looks like there is some problem with [ASP.NET Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) set up on this site. I went to the web.config and found the  configuration and set `enabled=false`. This solved my problem, and I was able to continue with the upgrade. I also found out that reenabling trace will break the backoffice even after the upgrade is complete. I will look into this more to find out if this is a problem specific to this umbraco site or if it is some sort of compatibility problem with ASP.NET Trace and Umbraco 7.5.8.

This was the problem:

```
<system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="true" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="false" />
```

This is the clue I found in the chrome inspector:

[image]